# How to get the Ender Dragon Egg to the Overworld

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I have traveled to the Ender "End" and beat the Ender Dragon at least 2 times. I have begun to notice that after killing the Ender Dragon, an egg appears near the Portal back to the Overworld. I guess it is the Ender Dragon egg, but when i hit it, the egg just "teleports" somewhere else. How do i get it to go to the overworld. When i am in creative mode, I looked in the spawn egg section and find no Ender Dragon spawn egg. So what do i do to spawn the ender dragon in the overworld?

And do i surround the ender dragon egg with tnt to destroy it?

Help please

Comment: Hey, dude.  Please don't challenge a closure in your question.  You can comment on your question to do so.

Comment: My question is really how to spawn the egg in the overworld.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The egg dropped after killing the dragon is a decorative item. It will never hatch into an ender dragon. If you still want it as decoration, build a platform underneath it and push it with a piston to break it. To spawn it in the overworld requires commands:

```
/summon ender_dragon
```